# Codeigniter .htaccess to remove index.php but what about sub-directory access?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a successful implementation of htaccess to remove index.php in codeigniter. Which meant that I can access any controller via domain.com/controllername.

However, I realized that with this implementation I cannot access sub-directory within the server via the URL. Please advice if there is a working solution to resolve such issue.

Thank you

The htaccess which I am using now is as follows

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|update\.php|administrator\.php|assets|admin|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 

<FilesMatch ".(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Not sure how to help you without seeing what your config looks like...

Comment: Terribly sorry, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark this may be the probable solution to your issue where you are unable to access the sub 
folders of the system.

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php #Here you write the line which will overwrite the index.php and will move the control to your controller.
```

The comments in the code are itself self speaking.
For more exact answer post your exact htacess you are using.
Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if your pointing out another site inside your domain aka sub-folder. Edit your .htaccess like this :

```
RewriteBase /domain.com/sub-folder/
```

or

```
RewriteBase /sub-folder/
```